# Function won't let me to display an error message outside of the function?

Tags: python, function

I have created a code which was trying to be a password checker, which checks if the inputted password was more than 8 characters, has an upper case and lower case character, and a number. However, when attempting to display an error message telling the user which aspect of the password they're missing (e.g. "Please include at least one lower case letter") it just will not display the error!

```
def passChecker():
  global errorMsg
  errorMsg=0
  valid=False
  while valid==False:
    pass_=input("Please create a password:\n")
    if len(pass_)>=8 and len(pass_)<=20 and valid==False:
     for i in pass_:
       if i==i.lower() and valid==False:
          for i in pass_:
            if i==i.upper() and valid==False:
              for i in pass_:
                if i.isdigit() and valid==False:
                  print("Password is valid.")
                  valid=True
                  break
              if valid==False:
                errorMsg==4
            else:
              errorMsg==3
        else:
            errorMsg==2
    else:
      errorMsg==1

passChecker()
if errorMsg==1:
    print("Please ensure your password is more than 8 characters long")
if errorMsg==2:
    print("Please ensure your password contains at least one lower case letter")
if errorMsg==3:
    print("Please ensure your password contains at least one upper case letter")
if errorMsg==4:
    print("Please ensure your password contains at least one digit")
```

When "Password" is entered, "Please create a password" is displayed

When "password" is entered, "Please create a password" is displayed

When "Password1" is entered, "Password is valid" is displayed and the code ends (which is correct)*

When "password1" is entered, "Password is valid" is displayed (which isn't right)**

*Meets all conditions
**Doesn't meet the "Requires an upper case" condition

Thanks for any help in advance :)

Comment: You shouldn't use a global variable, use a return and save is in a variable. You never set valid to False

Comment: This is what exceptions are for.

Comment: @michalwa Yes of course in reality you might well define various custom exceptions, but the OP is probably not at that stage yet, and integer error codes will do perfectly fine.

Comment: Not even custom exceptions, this is literally what `ValueError` is for. I think if you're learning a language it doesn't hurt to just stick to its way of doing things. Even if you don't understand something at first, you might as well learn it and realize how well it solves your problem.

Comment: Or if you really want to stick to this way of doing things you might as well just print the error inside the function itself and not bother returning anything.

Comment: @michalwa If you're going to use exceptions then you kind of end up having to choose between using _"Please ensure ...etc..."_ as the exception string, which doesn't really _read_ like an exception string to be honest, or else defining custom exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggested version that uses the error code as a return value from the function.

When you are checking whether it contains the various types of character, it will need to work regardless of what order they occur in.  An easy way (although certainly there are many alternatives) is to have boolean variables that you set when you find a character of the required type.  Note that `i == i.lower()` is not a correct test for a lower case letter, because it also evalutates `True` for non-letters; use `i.islower()` -- and similarly for upper.

```
def passChecker():

    pass_ = input("Please create a password:\n")

    if len(pass_) < 8 or len(pass_) > 20:
        return 1

    has_lower = has_upper = has_digit = False
    for i in pass_:
        if i.islower():
            has_lower = True
        elif i.isupper():
            has_upper = True
        elif i.isdigit():
            has_digit = True
            
    if not has_lower:
        return 2

    if not has_upper:
        return 3

    if not has_digit:
        return 4

    print("Password is valid.")
    return 0


errorCode = passChecker()

if errorCode == 1:
    print("Please ensure your password is between 8 and 20 characters long")
elif errorCode == 2:
    print("Please ensure your password contains at least one lower case letter")
elif errorCode == 3:
    print("Please ensure your password contains at least one upper case letter")
elif errorCode == 4:
    print("Please ensure your password contains at least one digit")
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you should go for `regex` patterns. To achieve this.
Like you should check for each case and store a boolean value instead.

You can take help from this code

```
validatePassword = (password) => {
        const atLeast8 = password.length >= 8 ? ON : OFF,
            oneNumber = /\d/.test(password) ? ON : OFF,
            oneCapitalLetter = /[A-Z]/.test(password) ? ON : OFF,
            oneSpecialCharacter = this.testPassword(password);

        return { atLeast8, oneNumber, oneCapitalLetter, oneSpecialCharacter };
};

testPassword = (str) => {
        const hasOneSpecialChar = /[~`!@#$%^&*()+=\-[\]\\';,/{}|\\":<>?]/g.test(str);
        const hasInvalidChar = /[^0-9a-zA-Z~`!@#$%^&*()+=\-[\]\\';,/{}|\\":<>?]/g.test(str);

        if (hasInvalidChar) {
            return INVALID;
        } else {
            if (hasOneSpecialChar) {
                return ON;
            } else return OFF;
        }
};
```

Then return as the validations you get.
This would be more systematic though.

The main focus of this answer is to give a brief idea about to use `regex` approach rather then doing it in nested if else